# how to implement trigonometric expressions using a programming language?

Tags: programming-languages, trigonometry

```
*Expression: 
    -(sqrt((a0+a1 cos wt +a2 cos 2wt )^2 +(a1sin wt +a2 sin 2wt)^2
    - ـــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــ
    - sqrt ((1+b1cos wt+b2 cos 2wt)^2 +(b1 sin wt+b2 sin2 wt )^2 

*variables:
    - a0=.2
    - a1=1.2
    - a2=a0=.2
    - b1=1.6
    - b2=.8
    - F=32KHZ
```

*Question:

- I am supposed to use a programming language (not matlab) to implement this exp and observe the o/p signal .... how can I do that and with what language if its even possible?

Comment: Do you need to calculate the above? Or do you need to be able to calculate an arbitrary not known beforehand expression?

Comment: i really don't know its not my field and its a weird assignment i need to write the above expression in a programming language  and then observe the o/p signal as a graph ?? can that be done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C#, you can use [`System.Math`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.aspx), I believe it has every function you need:

- Abs
- Exp
- Sin
- Cos
- Sqrt
- ... a lot of other methods ...

Data type depends on accuarcy you need, you can use `decimal` data type.

Example:

```
decimal a0 = 0.2;
decimal a1 = 1.2;

decimal result = Math.Cos(a0) * a1 - Math.Sqrt(a1);
```

Basically, most programming languages have some sort of math library, which should contain those functions.

Comment: do i just write the expression as it is or does it have a specific format?... sry i know nothing about programming :$

Comment: I've added simple example, it's some basic stuff, but you should be able to go furhter with it.

Comment: yes thank u i thing i can go on further with that example :) ...... last question can C# show me the o/p in form of a graph ?

Comment: You will have to crate drawing function by yourself (so you'll draw on a canvas) or you can try to find some graphs/charts controls which you can use to display your data (e.g. mscharts)

Answer (score 0):

What language?
 You can do that calculation almost with all programming language available nowadays, like C, PHP, Java, etc.

How to do that? That varying from one language to another, I give you an example with [python](http://www.python.org/) (console):

```
>>> import math [enter]
>>> x = 30 [enter]
>>> y = math.cos(x) [enter]
>>> y [enter]
>>> 0.15425144988758405
```

Note: most programming language implement its trig function as radian not degree, to convert radian to degree in python, use this function: `math.cos(math.radian(x))`

To visualize in a graph, there is library for python called [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/), it is widely used in python

Comment: the syntax of python is it similar to matlab ?

Comment: I don't know much about Matlab, but for some functions I think yes.